# Как проверять bluetooth статус android каждые несколько секунд

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

Мне нужно проверять **включен ли блютуз каждые несколько секунд**, если включен то ничего не делать, если выключен выводить соответствующе сообщение

Comment: Для чего каждые несколько секунд ? Что за задумка ?

Comment: От этого будет зависеть работа приложения. Например если пользователь выключит его то приложение перестанет отправлять данные на ардуино до того момента пока пользователь опять его не включит

Comment: Обычно, создавать какие либо циклы которые постоянно работают в приложении - не очень, ибо ресурсозатратно, предлогаю почитать про Observer - паттерн проектирования. И если на крайняк, RxJava

Comment: Хорошо сейчас прочитаю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создайте `BroadcastReceiver` для прослушивания изменения статуса подключения `Bluetooth`:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                                             BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
        switch (state) {
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
            Toast.makeText(this, "выключен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
};
```

Зарегистрируйте его в `OnCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

/* ... */

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

/* ... */

unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло еще немного доработал и вышло то что нужно

Comment: Советую отписываться от ресивера в onPause().